# How to better make Single resource edit page on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a main page and special information for this particular page, how to better implement the editing form at url, for example / home-page-edit / without /: id?

Comment: Please, add code of corresponding model and controller, and your attempt with form - it is unclear now what are you asking

Comment: how i see it
1st. create a model
2nd. make one record
3nd. in the controller make update to first record in model
4th. create index page with form

but, how i can catch put request on this index page?

maybe u know better solution?

Thanks

Comment: I want find a concept how this  make better, maybe u have some links to read about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.
1. Fetch edit page and form with the passed `params: id, and_other_params`
2. After loading edit form for specific resources based upon that params od value you can insert data.
3. Custom update action but updated based upon passed params and id.

** Please this may not be the ideal way for http-rest requests. Try to avoid this way.

Comment: Or maybe something like this. 1. Select first from db, then if not exist create and select. 2 On update - update selected ?